# ServiceStack 4: Ignore favicon.ico in Fallback Route

Tags: routes, servicestack, favicon, ignoreroute

I have a more or less static website build on ServiceStack.Razor, with the routes defined as the following patterns:
I am trying to ignore favicon.ico, but route the paths like "/" or "/en-us" to the HomeScenario.
Other sample routes are /{Lang}/cook or /{Lang}/cheer, etc.

Unfortunately, my current approach is not ignoring favicon.ico. I would like to implement this without hopefully writing a lot of extra code.

```
[FallbackRoute("/{Lang*}")]
public class HomeScenario : LocalizedRequest
{

}

public class LocalizedRequest
{
    public LocalizedRequest()
    {
        Lang = "en-us";
    }
    public string Lang { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the default request

```
[DefaultView("home")]
public object Get(HomeScenario request)
{
    var cacheKey = GetCacheKey ("home", request.Lang);
    return base.Request.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache (base.Cache, cacheKey, () => {
        var response = LoadJson<HomeScenarioResponse> (request.Lang, "home");
        return response;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just ignore requests in code:

```
[DefaultView("home")]
public object Get(HomeScenario request)
{
    if (base.Request.PathInfo == "/favicon.ico")
        return HttpError.NotFound(request.PathInfo);

    var cacheKey = GetCacheKey ("home", request.Lang);
    return base.Request.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache (base.Cache, cacheKey, () => {
        var response = LoadJson<HomeScenarioResponse> (request.Lang, "home");
        return response;
    });
}
```

Otherwise you can register a CatchAll handler further up the [Request Pipeline](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations) that handles unwanted requests, e.g:

```
this.CatchAllHandlers.Add((httpmethod, pathInfo, filepath) => {

    if (pathInfo == "/favicon.ico") 
        return new NotFoundHttpHandler();

    return null; //continue processing request
});
```